# In BigQuery Standard SQL how to get a median of a subet of rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data like

| day | product | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sun | apples | 10 |
| Sun | apples | 12 |
| Sun | apples | 13 |
| Sun | oranges | 15 |
| Sun | oranges | 16 |
| Mon | apples | 10 |
| Mon | oranges | 14 |
| Mon | oranges | 15 |

And I want for each day the overall median price and the median price just for apples like

| day | median_all | median_apples |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sun | 13 | 10 |
| Mon | 14 | 10 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `percentile_cont()`:

```
select distinct day,
       percentile_cont(price, 0.5) over (partition by day) as median_overall,
       percentile_cont((case when produce = 'apple' then price end), 0.5 ignore nulls) over (partition by day) as median_apple
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way which is actually more flexible (but does not provide linear interpolation)

```
SELECT
 day,
 APPROX_QUANTILES(price, 2)[OFFSET  (1)] AS median_all,
 APPROX_QUANTILES(case when product = 'apples' then price end, 2)[OFFSET  (1)] AS median_apples,
FROM t group by day
```